# Mac Pro powers down when starting up from SSD

Tags: mac, boot, ssd

I installed an Intel X25-M SATA 80GB SSD in my Mac Pro.

- Model Name: Mac Pro
- Model Identifier: MacPro3,1
- CPU: quad core Intel Xeon, 2.8 GHz, 12MB L2 Cache (per processor)
- RAM: 6GB
- Bus Speed: 1.6 GHz
- Boot ROM Version: MP31.006C.B05
- SMC Version (system): 1.25f4

I then used [Carbon Copy Cloner](http://www.bombich.com/) to clone my boot drive to the new SSD. This worked fine.

When I select the new SSD in *System Preferences* -> *Startup Disk* and restart I hear the chime and then the system will power down.

Holding down `ALT` (Option) allows me to select my original boot drive.

I used Disk Utility to repair the disk, but with no luck.

Comment: FWIW, when I installed a Momentus XT in my MacBook I cloned my old drive with SuperDuper! and it did not boot. I had to reinstall Mac OS X. As a test, can you install a vanilla OS X installation and see if that boots?

Comment: I have almost exactly the same setup (bit more memory and 160G X25-M, and it works just fine... although I didn't try to clone my system into the SSD, just did clean install. I'd assume that has something to do with the cloned OS. You could also try holding down command-V when booting to get to verbose mode, to see if OS X tells something useful about what it doesn't like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-installing Snow Leopard on to the SSD solved the problem and it **didn't** delete my user profiles and kept some settings.

After the install I did need to update to 10.6.4 and re-install the magic trackpad drivers. Other than that it was all fine.

Thanks for the re-assurance. Now my system is blazing fast!